# Is there a console command to see my velocity?

Tags: counter-strike-source

How can I make a velocity radar like this:

[image: screenshot]

In counter strike source what commands do I type in the console?

Comment: That speed line looks suspiciously like a server mod.

Answer (score 4):

Not entirely sure what you mean by "velocity radar", but you can try `Cl_showpos 1` which will n not only display your current posision but also display `velocity`.

To make life easier you can create a file called `autoexec.cfg` in your `cstrike/cfg/` directory and write there the commands that you want and when you open CS:Source, the console commands would be run automatically.

I hope this helps.